# Linking XSL to XML with HTML using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, xml, xslt

Okay, as the title says, i'm having problems linking my XML and XSL with my HTML code using JavaScript. I'm new to XML so go easy on me! Here is the XML portion:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="students.xsl" ?>
<CSET2200>
<student>
    <lastname>Hardy</lastname>
    <firstname>Zachary</firstname>
    <id>R09877743</id>
    <major>CSET</major>
    <age>28</age>
</student>
<student>
    <lastname>Boots</lastname>
    <firstname>Erin</firstname>
    <id>R00334423</id>
    <major>SPCH</major>
    <age>26</age>
</student>
<student>
    <lastname>Thorne</lastname>
    <firstname>Lilianna</firstname>
    <id>R55668890</id>
    <major>ENGL</major>
    <age>23</age>
</student>
<student>
    <lastname>Hopper</lastname>
    <firstname>Chance</firstname>
    <id>R66992278</id>
    <major>HIST</major>
    <age>22</age>
</student>
<student>
    <lastname>Laskey</lastname>
    <firstname>Chris</firstname>
    <id>R43346578</id>
    <major>ACCT</major>
    <age>21</age>
</student>
<student>
    <lastname>Starr</lastname>
    <firstname>Ernie</firstname>
    <id>R54456609</id>
    <major>PHARM</major>
    <age>25</age>
</student>
</CSET2200>
```

And here is the XSL sheet i'm using to style the XML document:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
<body>
<h2>Students</h2>
<table border="1">
  <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
    <th style="text-align:left">Last Name</th>
    <th style="text-align:left">First Name</th>
  </tr>
  <xsl:for-each select="CSET2200/student">
  <tr>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="lastname"/></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="firstname"/></td>
  </tr>
  </xsl:for-each>
</table>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Now, HERE, it the HTML portion with Javascript:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadXMLDoc (students.xml)
{
    if (window.ActiveXObject)
    {
        xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxm12.XMLHTTP");
    }
    else
    {
        xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    xhttp.open("GET", filename, false);
    xhttp.send("");
    return xhttp.responseXML;
}

function studentNames()
{
    xml = loadXMLDoc("students.xml");
    xsl = loadXMLDoc("students.xsl");
    if (window.ActiveXObject || xhttp.responseType == "msxml-document")
    {
    ex = xml.transformNode(xsl);
    document.getElementById("example").innerHTML = ex;
    }
    else if (document.implementation && document.implementation.createDocument)
    {
        xsltProcessor = new XSLTProcessor();
        xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(xsl);
        resultDocument = xsltProcessor.transformToFragment(xml, document);
        document.getElementById("students").appendChild(resultDocument);
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="studentNames()">
<div id="students"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I believe this latter portion is correct and feel that my problem lies with how i've linked the XSL to the XML in the first place. Any insight would be greatly appreciated in making this thing display properly. I don't truly need the provision for displaying it in IE but it's in there just in case.

Comment: So it appears the XML opens perfectly on Safari and Firefox, styling from the XSL document and all. However the XML will NOT open at all in Chrome. This means there's something wrong with the HTML/JavaScript portion.

Additionally, why won't my XML open at all in Chrome? Just blank space....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it's just because
 function loadXMLDoc (students.xml)
should be
 function loadXMLDoc (filename)

Comment: That was it. Such a small thing overlooked >.<

Thanks mate!